# How do I sum the values in the row of a 2D array separately, and sum the values in the column separately? (Java)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, sum, row, multiple-columns

I've tried to sum all the values in the row of my 2D array, but I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with the program.

The method where the problem is at the end of the program. I only tried to sum the row values here. I did not include my attempt to sum the columns because it is also wrong.

**salesReport.txt**

```
20
74
22
05
61
84
14
86
55
22
09
81
83
91
23
49
96 
45
41
45
26
77
77
19
84
03
65
91
31
62
73
92
49
93
43
36
69
05
96
54
59
84
14
16
49
35
28
51
60
98
42
61
59
40
01
98
85
80
90
20
22
43
54
71
47
35
81
86
04
61
60
34
35
08
14
44
90
51
27
50
73
53
75
52
19
72
86
41
17
04
46
11
45
25
21
66
96
48
98
06
61
38
11
96
19
63
32
03
11
30
84
80
17
73
90
40
69
55
90
92
```

**MY CODE**

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for the Scanner class
import java.io.File; // Needed for the File class
import java.io.IOException;

public class salesReport
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      // Create a Scanner object to read input.
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      // Declaration of variables
      int C,D,E;
      int[] A;
      int[][] B;
      int rows = 10;
      int columns = 12;

      // Method to read file
      A = arrayFile(rows * columns);
    
      // Declaration of 2D array
      B = new int[rows][columns];
   
      for(int r=0; r < rows; r++)
      {
         for(int c = 0;c < columns;c++)
         {
            B[r][c] = A[r*c+c];
         }
      }
    
      // Method to show array
      showArray(B);

      // Method to sum entire 2D array
      C = totalSales(B);
      System.out.println("Total sales for the year: $" + C);
      System.out.println();
      
      // Method to average the sum of the 2D array
      D = averagesSales(C);
      System.out.println("Average sales for the year: $" + D);
      System.out.println();
      
      // Method to sum value in the ROW ONLY
      E = totalDivisionSales(B);
   
   }
   
   // Method to read file
   public static int[] arrayFile(int a) throws IOException
   {
        // Create a Scanner object to read input.
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   
      int A[];
      A = new int[a];
   
      System.out.print("Enter the filename: ");
      String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
      keyboard.close();
   
      File file = new File(filename);
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
   
      int i = 0;
   
      while (inputFile.hasNextLine())
      {
         A[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
         i++;
      }
      inputFile.close();
   
      return A;
   }
   
   // Method to show array
   public static void showArray(int[][] B)
   {
      for(int r = 0;r < B.length;r++)
      {
         for(int c = 0;c < B[r].length;c++)
         {
            System.out.print(B[r][c] + "   ");
         }
         System.out.print("\n\n\n");
      }
    
   }
   
   // Method to sum entire 2D array
   private static int totalSales(int[][] B)
   {
      int total = 0;
   
      for (int r = 0;r < B.length;r++)
      {
         for (int c = 0;c < B[r].length;c++)
         {
            total += B[r][c];
         }
      }
      return total;
   }

   // Method to average the sum of the 2D array
   public static int averagesSales(int C)
   {
      int avg;
    
      avg = C / 120;
      return avg;
   }
   
   // Method to sum value in the ROW ONLY
   public static int totalDivisionSales(int[] B)
   {
    int sum=0;
    
      for(int r = 0;r < B.length;r++)
      {
       sum = sum + B[r];
      }
      return total;
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any explanation of what you are doing you seem to be going to a lot of trouble to sum the rows. But I think your problem is building your 2D array incorrectly.  I believe it should be like this:

```
for(int r=0; r < rows; r++) {
     for(int c = 0;c < columns;c++) {
                B[r][c] = A[r*12+c]; // <-- notice the 12
     }
}
```

Having said that

- you can sum the rows easily as you read them in and save them at the same time
- then you can do the column sums

```
int[][] rows = new int[10][];
int[] rowSums = new int[10];
for (int row = 0; row < rows.length; row++){
    int[] r = new int[12];
    for (int col = 0; col < r.length; col++) {
        int val = scanner.nextInt();
        rowSums[row] += val;  // sum rows
        r[col] = val;         // save value
    }
    rows[row] = r;
}


int rowNo = 1;
for(int sum : rowSums) {
    System.out.printf("row %2d = %d%n", rowNo++, sum);
}
```

- To sum the columns, the outer loop should iterate over them.
- Then the inner loop iterate over the rows for the current column.

```
int [] colSums = new int[12];
for (int col = 0; col < 12; col++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < rows.length; row++) {
        colSums[col] += rows[row][col];
    }
}
System.out.println();
int colNo = 1;
for (int sum : colSums) {
    System.out.printf("col %2d = %d%n", colNo++, sum);
}
```

prints

```
row  1 = 533
row  2 = 672
row  3 = 722
row  4 = 560
row  5 = 734
row  6 = 598
row  7 = 572
row  8 = 453
row  9 = 571
row 10 = 731

col  1 = 499
col  2 = 472
col  3 = 584
col  4 = 502
col  5 = 538
col  6 = 516
col  7 = 398
col  8 = 620
col  9 = 474
col 10 = 564
col 11 = 525
col 12 = 454
```

**NOTE**

This may be a problem as `int` division drops fractions. You may want to change  your `int` declarations to `double`.

```
   // Method to average the sum of the 2D array
   public static int averagesSales(int C)
   {
      int avg;
    
      avg = C / 120;
      return avg;
   }
```

Also `total` in your `totalDivisionSales` method should probably be `sum`

Comment: Some feedback would be appreciated.